# What's wrong with this usage of a template `using` declaration

Tags: c++, templates, using-declaration

What's wrong with the following usage of a template `using` declaration?

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> struct A {
    template <typename AnotherT1>
    using MyTemplate = A<AnotherT1, T2>;
};

template<class SomeA> struct B {
    using MyType = typename SomeA::MyTemplate<double>;
};

int main() {
    B<A<int, int>> b; (void)b;
}
```

`gcc 4.8.2` complains:

```
temp.cpp:17:46: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
     using MyType = typename SomeA::MyTemplate<double>;
                                              ^
temp.cpp:17:46: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
temp.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct B<A<int, int> >’:
temp.cpp:21:20:   required from here
temp.cpp:17:46: error: ‘typename A<int, int>::MyTemplate’ names ‘template<class AnotherT1> using MyTemplate = struct A<AnotherT1, int>’, which is not a type
```

Comment: `using MyType = typename SomeA::template MyTemplate<double>;`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thank you! It would be nice if you could make it a reply, in which you would kindly include a link where I will be able to learn about the need for this usage of the word `template`.

Comment: Please refer to the question of which your is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Reference this page.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0afb82ta.aspx

Modify like below:

```
using MyType = typename SomeA::template MyTemplate<double>;
```